How can i insert/ select into a table and delete copied records from original table?
I have a table ActivityTable and want to move some records to an Archive table and then delete those moved records from the main table ie the ActivityTable.
I am doing the following
 INSERT INTO ArchiveTable
   ([Id]  ,
   [Name],
   [Key],
   [RegDate],
SELECT top 1000
   [Id],
   [Name],
   [Key],
   [RegDate],       
   FROM ActivityTable
   WHERE registrationDate < cast(cast(dateadd(day, -10, getutcdate()) as Date) as DateTime) 


    DELETE
    FROM ActivityTable
    WHERE registrationDate <  cast(cast(dateadd(day, -90, getutcdate()) as Date) as DateTime)   

How can I be sure that the top 1000 that have been selected will be the exact 1000 that are deleted from the Activity Table?

Is it Sql Server? Add tag.

Use OUTPUT clause. It's atomic and effective.

Data Archiving Strategies for SQL Server

You can use a common unique identifier and transaction control.
This will ensure that all of the 1000 records you insert and select into ArchiveTable are the ones you delete from ActivityTable.
BEGIN TRANSACTION;

-- Create a temporary table to hold the IDs

CREATE TABLE #TempActivityIds (Id INT);

-- Insert IDs for the top 1000 records into the temp table

INSERT INTO #TempActivityIds (Id)
SELECT TOP 1000 [Id]
FROM ActivityTable
WHERE registrationDate < CAST(CAST(DATEADD(day, -10, GETUTCDATE()) AS DATE) AS DATETIME);

-- Next, insert the records into the ArchiveTable using the IDs from the temp table

INSERT INTO ArchiveTable ([Id], [Name], [Key], [RegDate])
SELECT [Id], [Name], [Key], [RegDate]
FROM ActivityTable
WHERE [Id] IN (SELECT [Id] FROM #TempActivityIds);

-- Delete records from the ActivityTable using the IDs from the temp table

DELETE FROM ActivityTable
WHERE [Id] IN (SELECT [Id] FROM #TempActivityIds);

-- Finally, drop the temp table

DROP TABLE #TempActivityIds;

COMMIT TRANSACTION;

Hope this helps!

I have over 30 Million records , so i assume i put it in a loop ?

Also , i assume i need to create the temp table and the column Id ?

It is more efficient and practical to perform the operation in batches using a loop, given the large volume of records. You should create the temp table with the appropriate columns, in order to store the IDs of the records being processed in each batch. If you want a code example I would gladly share it with you.

can the code be optimized by changing the "WHERE [Id] IN (SELECT [Id] FROM #TempActivityIds);" into a an inner join , if so how can i do this please ?

Use OUTPUT clause.
The whole operation is atomic. Therefore, it does not need an explicit transaction.
DELETE top(1000) ActivityTable
OUTPUT DELETED.*
INTO ArchiveTable
WHERE condition;


is this faster than above ? I am dealing with about 20 Million records

@Stacey - I can't say for sure. I think it will be a little faster. You'll have to test it yourself.
